# Why gets my code after end of file statement ignored?

Tags: java, eof

I'm currently trying an example from my textbook on learning java, but my code after an EoF statement just gets ignored by the compiler.

```
package lettergrades;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LetterGrades {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 0;
    int gradeCounter = 0;
    int aCount = 0;
    int bCount = 0;
    int cCount = 0;
    int dCount = 0;
    int fCount = 0;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n %s%n %s%n", "Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100", "Type the end-of-file indicator to terminate input", "on unix type <ctrl> d then press Enter","On windows type <Ctrl> z then press enter");
    while (input.hasNext()){
        int grade = input.nextInt();
        total += grade;
        ++gradeCounter;
        switch (grade/10){
            case 9:
            case 10:
                ++aCount;
                break;
            case 8:
                ++bCount;
                break;
            case 7: 
                ++cCount;
                break;
            case 6:
                ++dCount;
                break;
            default: 
                ++fCount;
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("%nGrade Report:%n");
    if (gradeCounter !=0){
        double average = (double) total/gradeCounter;
        System.out.printf("total of the %d grades entered is %d%n", gradeCounter, total);
        System.out.printf("Class average is %.2f%n", average);
        System.out.printf("%n%s%n%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d%n%s%d%n", "Number of students that received each grade","A: ", aCount, "B: ", bCount , "C: ", cCount, "D: ", dCount, "F: ", fCount);
  
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("No grades were entered");
    
}

}
```

This is the output i get :

```
 Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100

 Type the end-of-file indicator to terminate input

 on unix type <ctrl> d then press Enter

 On windows type <Ctrl> z then press enter
```

But when i input ctrl D and press enter, nothing happens. Why don't the printf and if statements work?

Comment: Seems to work ok for me.

Comment: Windows also uses the control-d for eof.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I was using Windows and BlueJ. I used control-d to exit.

Comment: I believe that control-z on linux is used to put the current process into the background.

Answer (score 1):

As e.g. @FredLarson is reporting, it's working fine for most. You're relying on EOF character resulting in sysin being closed, which will in turn cause scanner's `hasNext()` to return false.

Evidently, on your system, that isn't working. If you're running this inside an IDE's 'console', they often don't let you close sysin or work differently from the command line.

You can try to figure out which voodoo key combo ends things, but there is an alternative.

Instead of EOF, or in addition to EOF, make another symbol that ends inputs. Perhaps `0`, or 'END'. In the later case you can no longer rely on `nextInt`, you'd have to call `next`, check if it is `END`, if yes, stop accepting input, and if not, toss it through `Integer.parseInt` to end up with a numeric value.

Now you no longer have to mention various platforms in your console messages, and you avoid these issues.